# iPhone App Store. Client submitting question

Tags: iphone

I am writing an application which will be submitted by my client.
I don't want to give them my source code, what must I do?

Comment: This question is extremely vague. Provide more detailed information.

Comment: It's not vague if you're familiar with the terms. I've edited to clear it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to provide them the binary output as described in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_developer_program_user_guide/iphone_developer_program_user_guide__standard_program_v2.4.pdf) on the iPhone Program Portal. They then upload this binary file along with the meta data on iTunes Connect (also detailed in that doc).

The binaries must be compiled using the app store distribution certificate that was obtained from the program portal. If your client has not provided these then your application will not be accepted.

Comment: Can you clarify these steps a bit. Can I do it "as usual", that is build as "Archive" with my certificate and then skipping clicking on "submit" and instead send the compiled binary to my client?

Answer (score 2):

Goto
build/distribution-iphoneos/ inside that you have .app file compress it and that compressed file is to be sent to the client.

hope it helps u.

Comment: client can upload binary file using application loader directly.

Answer (score 2):

These are the following steps needed to build an iPhone app under an Apple Distribution License and upload it to the App Store.

1. Create A **CSR** from **Keychain Access** in a Mac machine. 
   Access Keychain Access as  Finder>>Applications>>Utilities>>Keychain Access.
       Upload this CSR while creating a Distribution Certificate.
   **An Apple License can have only one Apple Distribution Certificate.**
2. Download Distribution Certificate.
   Open Keychain Access.
   Access Keychain Access as  Finder>>Applications>>Utilities>>Keychain Access.
   Install the downloaded Distribution Certificate.
   Right Click on the Distribution Certificate and select **"Export Certificate"** and  save as Personal Interchange Certificate (.p12) format in destination Library>>Keychains.
3. For every **new application** we need to create **new Provisioning Profiles** under **one Apple Distribution Certificate.**
   For each **new Provisioning Profile**, we need to create a **new App Id.**
   So we need to create a  Adhoc and Appstore Provisioning Profile.
4. **Adhoc** Provisioning Profile is for **testing the app in apple devices.**
   **Appstore** Provisioining Profile is for **uploading the app to appstore.**
   Download the respective Provisioning Profile and double click on the profile to install it. 
   Delete all the previous profiles and just **retain the newly installed profile.**
5. Build the application by selecting the Code Signing Entity as the newly installed Provisioning Profile.

6   Upload the **ApplicationName.app.zip** file as the binary file in **Application loader** while uploading the application to appstore.

Reference: **https://developer.apple.com**

I believe this would be of some help to you.